# Storing Class object in Session, is it reference type?

Tags: c#, asp.net

- I have a Class X, and its object is objX, and I set properties for it and store it in Session.
- Create a another object objY of same type X. copied content of objX to objY
  like: objY = objX.
- Now, when I change properties of objX, it changes in objY.
- Even if I do like objY = (X)Session["objX"], it gives the same as objX

Why this is happening, how to avoid it?
How to avoid it?

Comment: Leave out sessions and try it out a vastly simplified version: `class X { public int a; }` and `objX = new X(); objY = objX; objY.a = 0; /* output objX.a */`

Comment: [Solved] Below is the solution
- Inherit "ICloneable"
- Implement the interface:
   ` #region ICloneable Members

        public object Clone()
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            bf.Serialize(ms, this);

            ms.Position = 0;
            object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
            ms.Close();

            return obj as AdminSecurityGroup;
        }

        #endregion
- `code` Session["mgo"] = ((AdminSecurityGroup)mg).Clone(); `code`

Comment: Do not mark a question as solved in the title. Just mark an answer as THE answer.

Comment: There is no "THE" answer in this discussion and more over I don't have  permission to mark as answer!

Comment: @avicool08 - StackOverflow is not a discussion site, it is a question/answer site. Can't you accept an answer?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd   No, My reputation is low!

Comment: Then make it higher by being a little active.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd   Ok shall try, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not cloning the objects, you're merely copying the references when you do objX =objY. Use a properly implemented clone method.

CLONE:

```
public Class X{
  public String A;
  public String B;
  public X Clone(){
     X cl = new X();
     cl.A = this.A;
     cl.B = this.B;
     return cl;
  }            
}
```

The syntax may not be 100% correct.

Comment: can you please give example how to do it?

Comment: OK, but a clone method is something pretty basic.

Comment: @CodeCaster    Did I mean its an Error? I just said, your answer didn't help me solving my problem, thats it!

Comment: I still think it should be the solution to your problem.